# Arduino Nano + L239DNE + external power supply

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, dc-motor, motor-controller

I want to build something with arduino and DC motor, so i'm using L239DNE to control speed and direction of the DC motor. Using some tutorial I hooked up everything together, but motor is just not giving out full power, connecting it directly to battery without IC makes it few times stronger.

So thinking that something is wrong with Arduino code or my layout I connected motor to IC using only battery, connected IN1 and ENABLE1 to VCC and IN2 to GND - still with same results, motor spinning much slower than it should.

This is my scheme now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBx3wD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can use the schematic editor to post actual schematics. You're not likely to get decent help with that img.

Comment: Oh, thank you, didn't find custom element before :).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid bipolar bridges - they are truly terrible, especially for low voltage projects.  These persist in the Arduino and related realms only because one uninformed person copies from another uninformed person without understanding what they are doing.

Comment: What would you recommend in this case? I need to control 6V motor speed + direction, with little loss as possible. @ChrisStratton

Comment: Current is typically the more difficult parameter than voltage.  TB6612FNG capabilities compare favorably to an L293 and it is often used as a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you mean L239 ....but actually mean L293

Here's the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf)

Since you are only using a 6 V DC supply for the motor, you most likely have too low a voltage across the motor for it to work properly. 
The output stages drop voltage and you can see from the datasheet you lose about 1.8 + 1.2 = 3 V for the upper and lower driver portion.

[image]

If you are using a 6 V motor I'd suggest you need at least a 9 V DC supply.

You could measure the voltage across your motor with a multimeter to verify this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant the L293DNE, not L293DNE. According to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf), the L293D can only provide up to 600mA of output current, which may be limiting the speed of your motor. You can check this by measuring the current through your motor with a multimeter while it is connected to the battery, and if it's greater than 600mA, you know your motor driver won't be able to drive it with the same amount of power.

Comment: "I'm assuming you meant the L293DNE, not L293DNE." - Aaawh yiiis.

Comment: No.  The issue is probably not the current, but rather the huge voltage loss in bipolar bridges.  The L293 and L298 and similar are truly terrible parts and **should not be used** given that there have been efficient MOS alternatives for over a decade.

Comment: The L293 does not limit the current at all. the 600 mA rating is the limit you need to design for. If you draw too much current you will overheat the device. The device does however limit the voltage drive due to the architecture of the driver. As Chris pointed out they are not an ideal driver.

Comment: @JackCreasey - it does have a thermal shutdown.  That appears to be all-or-nothing, though it's unclear what the time scale would be.  Probably long enough to appear as stuttering rather than a PWM type reduction of output.  But no, this isn't a helpful or informed response to the question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thermal shutdown is a 'whole chip' function, not a per output function so provides little current limit accuracy. There is no onchip current sensing at all.

Comment: As I said, it would probably be a thermal time constant stuttering at fastest - it wouldn't appear like a PWM reduction.